# Is there any way to apply styles to one of the elements in value? TextField from MUI | styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the `TextField` component from MUI and pass a `messagEdited useMemo function` to the `value` property.

`index.jsx`

```
import React, {  useMemo } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const hasComment = true;
  const comment = "this is a comment";

  const messageEdited = useMemo(() => {
    return hasComment ? `${comment} (edited)` : comment;
  }, [comment, hasComment]);

  console.log(`messageEdited:`, messageEdited);

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        variant="outlined"
        value={messageEdited}
        style={{ width: "350px" }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Is there any way to apply a style to the `(edited)` text that's in useMemo?

`styled-components`

```
export const Edited = styled.span`
  color: red;
`;

Edited.displayName = 'Edited';
```

#### Attempts

```
  const messageEdited = useMemo(() => {
    const EditedText = () => <Edited>edited</Edited>;
    return comment.editedText && !editEnabled
      ? `${commentText} ${EditedText()}} `
      : commentText;
  }, [comment.editedText, commentText, editEnabled]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, you can use `useState` for toggle `hasComment`

```js
import React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const hasComment = true;
  const comment = "this is a comment";

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{ input: { color: hasComment ? "red" : undefined } }}
        value={hasComment ? `${comment} (edited)` : comment}
        style={{ width: "350px" }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the problem here is I only need to apply the style to the `(edited)` text. I don't want `comment` to be `font -color: red;` .

Answer (score 0):

An [InputAdornment](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#input-adornments) can do the trick for you easily.

You can use `InputProps` for the TextField component and pass it your `<Edited/>` component conditionally.  The `InputProps` prop takes an object and the `endAdornment` property will set content visually at the end of the input.

Here's a super basic self-contained example:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

// Your Styled Component
const Edited = styled.span`
    color: red;
`;

// CommentField can receive an initialValue for a comment as a prop
// If the value is changed, the edited state is set to true and 
// the endAdornment value is set to the <Edited /> component

function CommentField({ initialValue = '', name }) {
    const [comment, setComment] = useState(initialValue);
    const [edited, setEdited] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setComment(e.target.value);
        setEdited(true);
    };

    return (
        <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            variant="outlined"
            value={comment}
            style={{ width: '350px' }}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name={name}
            InputProps={{
                endAdornment: edited ? <Edited>edited</Edited> : null,
            }}
        />
        
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <CommentField name={'comment1'} />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `(edited)` text needs to be right after the comment message like `this is a comment (edited)` but using the `endAdornment` displays `(edited)` right side of the text input.